# Ubuntu 12.04 shuts down suddenly when running on fully charged battery

Tags: linux, battery, power

When I use battery power in Ubuntu 12.04, it sometimes suddenly shuts itself down without any warning even though I am sure that the battery is almost fully charged. This never occurs when plugged in (charging). Can someone tell me what causes the sudden shutdown when using battery?

Comment: How do you know the battery is almost full? Where are you getting that information? Perhaps your system's ACPI driver isn't correctly interpreting the information it gets about battery state; if your system has a BIOS power warning option, such as an audible alarm on low battery, turn that on and see if it goes off before the laptop shuts down.

Comment: the power warning option is turn on, and sometimes it will alarm on low battery ,but these days i found that it will shutdown suddenly,what's more ,when it suddenly shutdown ,i can turn on the computer again ,and the battery state tell me it is almost full ,and a few time later ,i shutdown itself again ,without any alarming, so, may configuration cause that problem ?  thanks your answer !!

Comment: No answers yet? It has started happening to be recently with Ubuntu 16.04 and HP laptop.